# How to fix `next dev` esm import errors?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

When I run `next dev` on this project I get the following kind of errors. They are all caused by one internal library required by other internal libraries as dependency:

```
Module not found: ESM packages (@company/style-lib) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals
```

Pointing to this kind of line:

```
var style_lib_1 = require("@company/style-lib");
```

Which is inside this path:

```
./node_modules/@company/another-component-library/node_modules/@company/utils-lib/lib/cjs/components/Component/Component.js:51:0
```

So, it's a deeply embedded dependency that I can't change the import/export logic of. The strange part is that same project runs without issues on other teammates local environments. Also it used to run fine at one point on my Windows machine, until this error appeared. Worked fine on MacOS locally for a long time, until yesterday - until same issue appeared for what looked like no reason (no major project setup changes).

I tried (without any success) multiple times deleting `node_modules`, `yarn.lock`, cleaning npm cache and running again.

Also tried adding this to `next.config.js`

```
experimental: {
    transpilePackages: ['@company/style-lib'],
    esmExternals: true,
  },
```

I tried to debug by replacing all `require` statements with `import` ones, which just yielded this kind of errors:

```
TypeError: (0 , _company__style_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.styled) is not a function
```

This is module setup from `package.json` of `style-lib`:

```
{
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
...
}
```

The main project uses `volta` for node/yarn versions:

```
"volta": {
    "node": "16.13.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.17"
  }
```

Please let me know what kind of additional info could be helpful for solving this issue.

Comment: Can you show the real names and stack traces of your dependencies or are these packages you’re developing? Are there any `exports` defined in package.json?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `commonJS` if you are enabled `type: module` in `package.json`
try to use `ES6 Syntax`

`import styleComponent from "@company/style-lib";`

Comment: It's not feasible to me to change require to import inside `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by NOT deleting `yarn.lock`, only removing `node_modules` and running `yarn`.
For good measure I also deleted the `.config/yarn/Data/link` containing `@company` folder with other library, not one of the offenders here.